# How can I extract an edge like with Snapchat's scissor tool?

Tags: opencv, extract, edge-detection, snapchat

In Shapchat's photo editor, there is a scissor tool extract object with guiding lines (by drawing edges of object want to extract).

I wanted to implement that tool with openCV, but I am totally new to openCV. I searched openCV documents and tutorials, but I have no idea how to use and combine functions of finding contours, image moments, and edge extraction.

Comment: You may look at OpenCV GrabCut implementation, there are a lot of interactive demos, You can assume the inner edge of scissor line as sure foreground and outer edge as sure background and internal area of scissors as probable foreground/background, after labelling the regions, Grabcut will do the rest of work for you :)

Comment: @ZdaR That's what I want! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is:

1. Start with OpenCV's grabcut demo [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/grabcut.cpp)
2. Add code to draw a polygon using mouse events, or touch events.
3. Use the the polygon to initialize foreground region of grabcut segmentation.

You can also look at [dlib's image segmentation](http://dlib.net/imaging.html#segment_image), in which case the region cut by scissors can be used to extract parts of the segmented image.